# AC being turned on when calling for humidity

Tags: furnace

My newly installed Skuttle HSP2000 steam humidifier, controlled by a Generalaire GFX3 humidistat and wired to a Lennox G40UH-48B-090-14 is turning on the AC when being called for humidity. I've verified all wiring

Comment: Can you post wiring diagrams + photos of the wiring please?

Comment: just to be certain, do you have a smart thermostat? Ensure it isn't set to reduce humidity, you may have your system fighting itself.

Comment: An AC doubles as a de-humidifier (just in case that's not known).

Comment: Is it actually running the compressor or just the air handler?